# Audit a command with a parameter under Linux

Tags: linux, audit

I want to use audit function of Linux to audit a Linux command `date -s`. If I write `-w /bin/date -p x -k system-call` in `audit.rules`, it will record when I use the command `date`. But I don't want it to record when I use `date`. I only want it to record when I use `date -s`, which means someone changes the system's time. How I can write the rules?

Comment: I think you have to log all uses of the commands and then filter the logs for the options you care about. Note that someone could write `date -f somefile -s`, `date --set=1234`, etc. so it isn't enough to filter on `-s` as the first argument.

Comment: Because it produce to much logs so I want to do this.@Gilles